# How can I use R Regular Expressions to catch a Hebrew word?

Tags: r, regex, hebrew

I've been trying to catch the word 
עונה 
plus the subsequent number after it in a string such as

כל הילדים אוכלים, עונה 2 , פרק 8-לזניית ירקות וסלמון בדבש

Demonstrating it on Regex101.com was straightforward enough, with עונה(\s+\d+|\d+), but with R I came up empty.

```
str<-"כל הילדים אוכלים, עונה 2 , פרק 8-לזניית ירקות וסלמון בדבש"
exp<-"עונה(\\s+\\d+|\\d+)"
str_extract_all(str,exp)

Output:
[[1]]
character(0)
```

Comment: Please check your locale settings as I get `str_extract_all(str, exp)[[1]]#
[1] "עונה 2"`

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")

Comment: @akrun 
Can you send us your locale settings if you were successful?

Comment: [עונה(\s*\d+)](https://regex101.com/r/ikRpmR/1)

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew") should work

Comment: mine is utf-8. `Sys.getlocale()#
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux or MacOS? Here is an R 3.5.2 demo on Linux, it is [working there](https://ideone.com/ABxCHB).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/[\u0590-\u05FF]/*
```